# Windows 8 app blue screen after loading UI

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

While running performance tests my application suddenly started giving blue screen shortly after the UI was loaded.

In the code im receiving the following error:

> {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}
>   "The GPU device instance has been suspended. Use GetDeviceRemovedReason to determine the appropriate action.\r\n"

After looking around on google i wasn't able to find anything usefull. The main answers given didn't work such as installing driver updates or reinstalling the application. Keep in mind this is an app in development and it was working fine earlier this day. Between two test launches this happened.

EDIT
After testing the application on a tablet it turns out the development pc is the only machine with the UI loading bug. Going to look into it some more and ill let you guys know if i find a solution.

Edit 2
So after testing the app on the tablet and finding that it works fine there we decided to test the app on a 2nd development pc. Needless to say the same thing happened... in other words its a rendering issue that happens on windows 8.1 PC's but not on a tablet.

Facts as of now:
- Code worked yesterday, no longer works now
- Works on tablet but not on PC
- Nothing changed in the code since it worked
- Seems to happen in the rendering stages
- Bug happens when loading more than 23 items in a listview, app restores itself then
- Any more than 23 items and it stays bugged (dark blue screen but still responds to clicks)

Comment: Ya, you have to love that one. In my experience it's always been some little nuance issue with your xaml. Like something pointing to a Brush that only accepts a color, or a dependency property somewhere set erroneously to an invalid resource etc. Might share some XAML to better diagnose.

Comment: got roughly 11 xaml pages so sharing would most likely be pointless :) ill start looking into any possible 
XAML errors... least now i have a clue where to look... strange thing is that i had already loaded the page + - 8 times before it suddenly started doing this...